# Espresso with support.v4 ViewCompat throws NoSuchMethodError on load

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm using **Espresso** to automate my app testing. My app has 1 ActionBarActivity and 1 fragment using android.support.v4.app.Fragment. The app works fine but when I attempt to run a Espresso test, I get an error when launching app.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isLaidOut(Landroid/view/View;)Z in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat' appears in /data/app/com.example.android.app.test-1/base.apk)
    at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.setDecorPadding(ContentFrameLayout.java:73)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.applyFixedSizeWindow(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:428)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:403)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:246)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
    at com.example.android.app.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:346)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2407)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5321)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1016)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)

    Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError'
```

I'm using Android Studio.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add the code that's causing the crash? (your onCreate method of MainActivity)

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 …….
}

Comment: I meant as an edit in the actual post. As a comment I can't see anything

Answer (score 2):

Exclude support-v4 from the espresso-contrib library.

```
   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2') {           
         exclude module: 'support-v4'
   }
```

Comment: It is working...! Thanks for your help. But, Please give explain about How does it work?. because I am newer in espresso.

Comment: If you run ./gradlew app:dependencies you can see that there is a conflicting support-v4 dependency in both your app and espresso-contrib library. Conflict generally occurs when versions of the dependencies don't match. In your case espresso most likely was depending on older version of the support-v4 library than your app. More on dependency management and version conflicts: https://docs.gradle.org/1.9-rc-3/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:version_conflicts